# Deleting rows in a CSV via shell script based on a columns value

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I'm very inexperienced with shell scripts, and I need to write one that deletes an entire row when a column named Views contains the value 0. The column "Views" may not always be in the same location in the file, so I would need some way to find the location of the column before hand. Is this something that is feasible with sed or awk? Or is there something else that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show example input and output? I'd like to see the way the headers are formatted, in particular.

Comment: @Wintermute hey yea, so its just a standard CSV. The headers are the first line of the file: Date,....,Views,...,URL. The sample output would be the exact same CSV file, just with rows with 0 views removed from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk, this could be done like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { col[$i] = i }; next } $col["Views"] != 0' filename.csv
```

`-F,` sets the field separator to a comma, since you mentioned a CSV file.
The code is

```
NR == 1 {                    # in the first line
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { # go through all fields
    col[$i] = i              # remember their index by name.
                             # ($i is the ith field)
  }
  next                       # and do nothing else
}

$col["Views"] != 0           # after that, select lines in which the field in
                             # the column that was titled "Views" is not zero,
                             # and do the default action on them (i.e., print)
```

Note that this will only filter out lines where the `Views` column is exactly 0. If you also want to filter out lines where the `Views` field is empty, use `$col["Views"]` instead of `$col["Views"] != 0`.

Comment: This looks pretty good, but the only issue is its just being output on the console. I need those rows to be physically deleted from the file. Is this possible with awk?

Comment: With GNU awk 4.1.0 or later, use `awk -i inplace same_as_before_here`. Or, because it is nice to have a backup in case the power goes out at the wrong moment, `cp foo.csv foo.csv~ && awk same_as_before foo.csv~ > foo.csv`.

Comment: it doesn't look like those rows are being skipped. Are we sure that this part is right col[$i] = i 

i is the index of the fields isn't it? So $col["Views"] would be set to the index rather than the actual value contained in that column, which is what needs to be checked against 0 for every line in the file

Comment: `$i` is not the value of `i`, it's the value of the `i`th field. In the same vein, `$col["Views"]` is the value of the `col["Views"]`th field. Can you add some input data to the question so I can see what's different in my guessed test data? It works for me.

Comment: Looks like I copied it wrong. It's working now for me. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW I'm never sure if `$col["Views"]` will be parsed as `($col)(["Views"])` or `$(col["Views"])` by all awks so I always explicitly write it as the latter. I think it helps the clarity anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i=="Views"){x=$i;y=i}}};NR>1{if($y!=0){print}}'  file > new_file
```

breakdown of code

```
NR==1{                    #for the first line 
print                     #print it 
for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){       #make a loop to read all the column and find the 
    if($i=="Views"){      #name "Views" in the first row. 
        y=i               #Save the column number in a variable named y
    }
}
}

NR>1{                     # start from line 2 going downwards targeting
     if($y!=0){           # the Views Column
       print              #if it does not contain 0, print the line
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '($1 == "badString") && !($1 ~ /[.]/) { next } 1' inputfile > outputfile
```

#if first column = badString or has . (dot) dont include it in outputfile